# storing and retrieving an instance of a class in a hashtable

Tags: java, hashtable

So I am trying to store an instance of a class in hash table:

```
 public void insertEdge(String val1, String val2, int len) {
       Hashtable ref = new Hashtable(10, 3); 

       if(!ref.containsKey(val2))
       {
           Vert temp = new Vert(val2);
            ref.put(val2, temp);
           curNod++;
       }

       ref.get(val1).firstEdge = new Edge(ref.get(val2), ref.get(val1).firstEdge, len);
}
```

When I run the program above the compiler returns the following error:

```
error: cannot find symbol

       ref.get(val1).firstEdge = new Edge(ref.get(val2), ref.get(val1).firstEdge, len);
```

I am still learning hashtables so go easy.
from what I understand you should be able to store an instance of a class in hashtable and retrieve it, `firstEdge` is a variable of my class `Vert`so I in theory I should technically be able to retrieve it without a problem!

Here is the `Vert` class

```
class Vert {
   public Edge firstEdge;
    public String name; 

   public Vert() {
      firstEdge = null;

   }

    public Vert(String n)
    {
        firstEdge = null;
        name = n;   
    }
}
```

Comment: What are `val1` and `val2`? Can you post that relevant part of the code too?

Comment: I have updated the question to include `val1` and `val2` but they are strings used as keys for hashtable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not annotating your Hashtable. So `ref.get(val1)` returns an `Object` class and you are trying to get `firstEdge` which is not a property of `Object` class. You'll either have to initialize your hashtable like `Hashtable<String, Vert> ref = new Hashtable<String, Vert>(10, 3);` or cast `((Vert)ref.get(val1)).firstEdge`

Comment: ok that is exactly what I needed and good explanation. Thanks. one last question, isnt `object` the parent class of all the other objects in Java? shouldnt it be compatible with a class I write?

Comment: Yes of course it is the parent class, but parent doesn't has visibility on child fields. Child can see public and protected property of parent.